# Android studio Log.i() unable to log all lines inside a for loop

Tags: android

I was troubleshooting some issues and wanted to check the list items in a for loop, expecting to see all items. In the end I found items can be skipped. My testing as follows:

1. in MainActivity button onClick, to log 1000 items, but it stopped at 495

```
        btnSetting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                    //testing logging
                    for (int n=0; n<1000; n++)
                    {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Testing Log.i  "+n + "/"+1000);
                    }
                }
                /*
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ConfigActivity.class);

                startActivity(intent);*/
            }
        });
```

The results stopped at 495:

```
    ...
    2023-12-31 06:52:52.127  1826-1826  [dbg]MainActivity I  Testing Log.i  493/1000
    2023-12-31 06:52:52.127  1826-1826  [dbg]MainActivity I  Testing Log.i  494/1000
    2023-12-31 06:52:52.127  1826-1826  [dbg]MainActivity I  Testing Log.i  495/1000
```

2. in a sub-screen button onClick, before finish() to return MainActivity, random items skipped

```
        2023-12-31 06:46:23.811 29705-29705 [dbg]CreatePattern  I  Testing Log.i  0/1000
        2023-12-31 06:46:23.811 29705-29705 [dbg]CreatePattern  I  Testing Log.i  1/1000
        2023-12-31 06:46:23.811 29705-29705 [dbg]CreatePattern  I  Testing Log.i  2/1000
        2023-12-31 06:46:23.811 29705-29705 [dbg]CreatePattern  I  Testing Log.i  5/1000
        2023-12-31 06:46:23.811 29705-29705 [dbg]CreatePattern  I  Testing Log.i  23/1000
        2023-12-31 06:46:23.811 29705-29705 [dbg]CreatePattern  I  Testing Log.i  26/1000
        2023-12-31 06:46:23.811 29705-29705 [dbg]CreatePattern  I  Testing Log.i  28/1000
        2023-12-31 06:46:23.811 29705-29705 [dbg]CreatePattern  I  Testing Log.i  29/1000
        2023-12-31 06:46:23.811 29705-29705 [dbg]CreatePattern  I  Testing Log.i  30/1000
        2023-12-31 06:46:23.811 29705-29705 [dbg]CreatePattern  I  Testing Log.i  35/1000
        2023-12-31 06:46:23.811 29705-29705 [dbg]CreatePattern  I  Testing Log.i  37/1000
        ...
```

Has anyone encountered the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a normal occurrence and always happens when lines have to be written in the `logcat` faster than the system can process them (the `logcat` has no queue, pending lines are ignored). If you make the loop slower, e.g. with an additional mathematical calculation such as `double d = Math.sin(n);` ), you will see more, perhaps already all values of `n` in the logcat.